# As an addendum you'd use my prefix, Almost in your hand you can find my suffix,

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme

OK, let me try my hand at this:

> As an addendum you'd use my prefix
>   Almost in your hand you can find my suffix
>   My infix is even more thin than a hair
>   And some might find me on a wing and a prayer

What am I?

Comment: Do we have to put usernames in the title like that? Feels like people are becoming 'brands' :-/

Comment: No, but I tried 3 different titles and all of them turned up as duplicate titles.  So I gave up and picked a title I was sure would be unique :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is

> PSALM.

*As an addendum you'd use my prefix*

> PS at the end of a letter.

*Almost in your hand you can find my suffix*

> ALM is almost like the PALM of your hand.

*My infix is even more thin than a hair*

> The infix is actually nothing, because there are no letters between PS and ALM in the word.

*And some might find me on a wing and a prayer*

> PSALM.

Comment: You didn't get the 3rd line meaning correct but the other 3 lines are all correct.

Comment: The explanation for the 3rd line is rot13(gurer ner ab yrggref orgjrra cf naq nyz va gur jbeq cfnyz, fb gur vasvk vf rzcgl)

Comment: @Ertai87 Ah, OK. Often in these riddles the infix overlaps with the prefix and/or suffix.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't clear on that.  I'll take note of that for my next one, thanks :)